# Work out the value of k in $y = \frac13 x^3 - x^2 -3x + k$

Tags: calculus, cubics

I'm finding this question really difficult, it's on the further maths GCSE and has a cubic graph picture below it.  If that would help, let me know.

$$y = \tfrac13 x^3 - x^2 -3x + k$$

where $k$ is a constant.

The $x$ axis is a tangent to the curve at its minimum point. Work out the value of $k$.

I know basic differentiation but don't know where to start on this. I'm a GCSE Further Maths student so I don't have a vast amount of mathematical experience; please be patient and explain in steps.

Comment: Are you familiar with derivatives?

Comment: I have a basic knowledge of the conscept.

Comment: The derivative of a function is zero at the function's maxima and minima. So you have two tasks: 1) find derivative 2) figure out to use derivative to find value of $k$.

Comment: Sorry, that's too advanced for me at this stage. Could you please break this down further?

Comment: It's hard to imagine how one might tackle this problem without an understanding that the derivative of a differentiable function is zero at its local extrema (local minimum in this case).  You say you have "a basic knowledge" of derivatives, so you should be able to differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$ (treat $k$ as a constant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume when you say minimum point, you mean local minimum.

To find the local maximum or minimum of a function, you first find the derivative. In this case, the derivative is $x^2-2x-3$. Next you would set the derivative equal to $0$, which would give you $x=3$ and $x=-1$.

Since this is a cubic function, one of these is a local max and the other is a local min. To find which is a local min, you would first find the 2nd derivative of the function (the derivative of the derivative) which is $2x-2$. The $x$ value for which the 2nd derivative is positive is the local min. Therefore in this case, $x=3$ is the local min.

Since the $x$-axis is tangent to the local min, that means when $x=3$, $y$ must equal $0$.  You can now just plug those values into the equation and solve for $k$.

Comment: Much appreciated man. This explains very well.

Comment: No problem.  If you like an answer, you can upvote it and mark it as accepted.